# Jest Call retries were exceeded

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

I have error in the following below test. My node version is : v12.10.0. is there any alternative of setTimeout?

```
   test('demo code', async () => {
        const cc = await projectSetup(project);
        const onNotification = jest.fn();
        cc.sendNotification();
        await waitForExpect(() => {
            expect(onNotification).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        });

    });
```

The Error log is as

```
Call retries were exceeded

  at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (../../../node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:230:21)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code?

Comment: This is a known error in Jest related to the version of node.  If you change your node version to 13.3.0 that is supposed to fix it, if that works for you please respond to this comment to let us know.  That didn't work for me.  Also, someone said they increased the memory on the CI server.  See the details here:  https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8769

Comment: changing node version, did't work for me. I increased the default timeout but this is not a good solution

Comment: How did you increase the timeout @HammadQureshi?

Comment: just add  }, 15000) as a parameter, the default time is 3 seconds and in this way I increased the default time

Comment: I faced this issue. Found an Open issue on the repo: Please see my comment; https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8769#issuecomment-1463882800

Answer (score 13):

just add `jest.useFakeTimers();` after your imports

```
...
jest.useFakeTimers();

test('demo code', async () => {
        const cc = await projectSetup(project);
        const onNotification = jest.fn();
        cc.sendNotification();
        await waitForExpect(() => {
            expect(onNotification).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        });

    });
```

it works in my code

Comment: You can also just add `jest.useFakeTimers()` in your `jest.config.js` setup file, eliminating the need to add it after the imports in every file, if you have setup your project to use it. It worked for me.

Comment: @instanceof how did you include jest.useFakeTimers() intro jest.config.js file? I've a module.export = { <several objects inside> }. I've tried to include ```fakeTimers: {
    enableGlobally: true,
  },``` inside but it gives me "Unknown option" when I run the tests. How should I insert it?

Comment: @SebastianDiaz check [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#faketimers-object) to add it in your jest config file.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the actual problem was with the promise handling.
I got the same issue when I was running all my test cases in one go with the jest.

**Solution:**
Try running one test separately then see what error is coming.

I got the below error after running one problematic test separately where earlier I was getting the `Call retries were exceeded`:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

With this, I was sure that the problem is with the catch block and when I added it in the async service API function then the test case worked perfectly fine.
Maybe you can also try the same and see if it works for you or not.

I am using the below config:

**node:** 15.13.0

**npm:** 7.8.0

**jest:** 26.6.3

Comment: Running the failing tests alone DOES reveal the actual error indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try running `npm doctor` using the latest npm version. It's a great tool and it helped me diagnose permission and ownership issues right away.

Takeaway:

Verify File/Folder Permissions & Ownership

Answer (score 1):

Encountered same error when updating the vue-jest version to below listed versions

- @vue/vue3-jest: ^27.0.0-alpha.4
- @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest: ~5.0.0,
- node: v17.9.0 or v16.14.2

Error disappeared, once downgraded it to node version v14.x.x

Hunch is - the latest node versions are not compatible with the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the test's successfully doing the following;

1. Install `npm i -D jest-canvas-mock`

Update the jest.config.ts file to have:

```
  export default {
...
testEnvironment: "jsdom",
setupFiles: ["jest-canvas-mock"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it works for me:
axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: [] }));

PS: change get to post incase you are using POST method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).